# Writing an array of shorts to a file

Tags: c++, file-io

For some reason (that I've yet to figure out), the following code doesn't quite work as expected. I'm trying to write an array of shorts to a file and while the file is generated successfully, the values are just not right. The example code is

```
short* sarray = new short[2000];
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
    sarray[i]=i*2;

    FILE* oFile;

    oFile =  fopen("E:\\audio_rec\\test_1.raw", "w");

    int shortsRead =fwrite(sarray, sizeof(short), 2000, oFile);
    fclose(oFile);
```

The file content (as displayed in a hex editor). It's clear that only the first 5 values (up to 8) are as expected. 
Any ideas?

[image: hex dump]

Thanks

Comment: bp should have been sarray. That was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows you need to tell [fopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) that the data is binary or it messes up "\n" to "\r\n".

```
fopen("E:\\audio_rec\\test_1.raw", "wb");
```